# What does it mean if the determinant equals $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If the determinant is non zero, then it means that the system of equations represented by its matrix has a unique solution.  If the determinant is zero, then it must mean that the system is a) inconsistent, or b) has infinitely many solutions.  Which is it, a) or b)?

Comment: inconsistent means it has no solution.  so it can't be both.

Comment: Both (a) and (b) are possible. Consider the systems:
$$\begin{cases}
x+y=0 \\ x+y=1 \end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} x+y=1 \\ 2x+2y=2 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 4):

The simplest matrix with determinant $0$ is the $1\times 1$ matrix $[0]$. It represents equations of the form
$$
0x = b
$$
for some real number $b$. Think of a real number $b$ that makes the system inconsistent, and a real number $b$ which makes the system have infinitely many solutions.

So if the coefficient matrix of a system of equations has determinant $0$, then the system is either inconsistent, or it has infinitely many solutions. You can't tell which one it is just from the matrix, though.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  Your example shows that the system is inconsistent unless b = 0.  If b = 0, then it has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @LaddWebster Exactly. And similar things happen in any dimension. It's just a bit more work to figure out exactly which $b$'s give infinitely many solutions and which ones are inconsistent.

Comment: The system has infinitely many solutions only for homogeneous systems.  In the non-homogeneous case, it is inconsistent.  Again, thanks.

Comment: @LaddWebster It's not always about the homogenity (see the examples you got in the comments to your question post). But in $1\times 1$, that's the only example, and the homogenous case will _always_ give you infinitely many solutions, since the zero vector is a solution, and you can't have just $1$ solution. However, often you get infinitely many solutions in non-homogenous cases as well (in fact, if your matrix isn't the zero matrix, there will necessarily be non-homogenous systems with infinitely many solutions).