# Determinant equal to zero, what does it mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I understood correctly, a $determinant = 0$ means that the matrix has no area/volume/etc. But if a system of equations, say $Ax = b$ has a unique solution $x$, does that mean that the determinant can't be zero in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because if the determinant is zero, then the system is either inconsistent (no solutions), or it has infinitely many solutions.

Assuming the determinant is defined (which means that you must have a square matrix), you can just take the inverse of the matrix. If the inverse exists, this will give you exactly one, unique solution.

See this other Math SE post: [what does it mean if the determinant equals 0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136095/what-does-it-mean-if-the-determinant-equals-0?rq=1) for more on this topic.